# Absolute positioned element with full width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a mega-menu. I'm using a list element and some elements have divs inside.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<li class="list-item">
<a href="#">Marchés</a>
<div class="sub-menu-wrap">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Marché 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</li>
```

The `li` with `.list-item` class has `position:relative;` and the `.sub-menu-wrapper` has `position:absolute;` and `width:100%;`

i need the `.sub-menu-wrap` to have a full screen width but it's only taking the `li.list-item` width (screenshot below).

[image]

I also tried left:0;right:0; for `.sub-menu-wrap` but nothing changed..

Comment: i like to use the new vw/vh measure. You would use it like `<ul class="sub-menu" style="100vw">` if i understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Paulquappe, I have tried it and it works, but i'd like to avoid it if there is an alternative, because i will have to center the .sub-menu-wrap using transform and left properties, and i'd like to understand what am i doing wrong and why it's not working width width 100%.

Answer (score 0):

When recreating your code, the element positioned absolute does in fact take up 100% width when the width is set to 100%.  Double check your syntax.  See my snippet below, the element positioned absolute is taking up the full width.

```css
.list-item{
   position: relative;
   background: lightcoral;
   width: 100px;
}
.sub-menu-wrap{
   position:absolute;
   background-color: lightblue;
   width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-item">
<a href="#">Marchés</a>
<div class="sub-menu-wrap">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Marché 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marché 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: The problem is that i can't give the list item a full width, it has a limited width as there are other elements.

Comment: if list-item as a width sub-menu-wrap will take this width

Comment: I have seen an example where it works so i'm trying to understand what's different. you can check it here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_mega_menu.asp

Comment: The 'list-item' is your entire code container (within your example at least).  I'm not sure why you have labeled as such, I assumed this was only part of a larger project.  But yes, if you limit the '.list-item' width, then the children elements would scale because they are using percentages.  In that case, 'vw' would work but you said you can't use that in the opening comments.  You could then attempt to set widths by Pixels instead as an option.

Comment: Thanks @skaz, but i can't use width in pixels either as it will cause responsiveness issues. I guess i will set the li position:initial; and set a parent who has width:100%; to position:relative; this way my content will have a full width.